# How Would I Update a Variable Every Minute And Send It To My Webserver?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, backend

I have an API call that returns a simple variable, but this variable rarely changes, so making that API call every time the user refreshes the page is inefficient, so I thought of creating a server side that calls this algorithm every minute, and then updates that variable in my website's javascript, so that if 10 users were to visit the page, it wouldn't need to call the API 10 separate times, because it would already be a local variable.

I've got Node.js ready, but have been looking for ways to do this and coming up totally empty, anyone wanna help me out?

Comment: Make your API call from node js and store the result of that call then have your javascript on the client retrieve it

Comment: So if you're talking Node, why the PHP tag?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: You could always just cache it for 60 seconds, and have one unfortunate user do the update, also if done with ajax then blocking is mitigated.

Comment: @Pratansyah That's what I'm trying to do, the part I'm stuck at is how to have javascript retrieve the variable from Node.js

Comment: @nnnnnn For all I know this could be done 10x simpler in PHP, if so I'd want to know.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone Where would I cache the variable? I've only seen local storage and web storage and both are client side, so a user would only need to refresh it once, but with quickly updating variables and many users that would inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a nodejs server side call with something like expressjs
   first.
2. To call the service for you, if it is a http call use the http/https
   module, if the api has a module use the module.
3. Save this variable into a global variable in nodejs or use a cache.
4. Set a timeout for whatever period you would like and at the end of
   the timeout clear the variable.
5. Create an endpoint to return the variable if it exists or call the service and return the value

Comment: I understand how to get the variable and cache it with Node, but don't know how I would communicate between Node and my javascript?

Comment: See this trivial example  
    const express = require('express')
    const app = express()

    app.get('/variable', (req, res) => res.send('Variable'))

    app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))

your logic would go into the variable endpoint and you would call this value from your browser by using ajax